# "packages" property in log4j2

Tags: xml, properties, package, log4j, log4j2

I would need to set the property "packages" in file property:

...

I can find only the xml way to do it, but in my project I can only do it via properties.
How can I set the property "packages" in property?

I need it because at the moment the application can't detect a plugin which I created and annotated with @Plugin

I am using log4j2.

Answer (score 0):

```
packages = com.example.package,com.example.package2
```

Comment: This is waht I tried , but it didn't work. It might have been a local problem though. I moved to xml to make it work